# Parallel sorting two different lists using jquery sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am having very specific case where I needed to split the data into two different lists in html. Like this:

```
<ul id="first_list">
    <li ref="1">The quick brown</li>
    <li ref="2">My father works</li>
</ul>
```

And the second list is like:

```
<ul id="second_list">
    <li ref="1">jumps over the lazy dog</li>
    <li ref="2">at the Ministry of Defense</li>
</ul>
```

So as you can see I from the "ref" attribute I know which `<li>` element from the second list is a continuation of which `<li>` element from the fist list.

Now I need to enable the jQuery UI sortable() to those lists but when I reorder the first I need the second reordered too. I tried using handle but it doesn't works because it looks like the handle element needs to be inside the element which is moved but these two are at a different places in the page.

Comment: Are you talking about jquery ui sortable

Comment: Young chap, this is not a "I am willing to pay if someone comes up with a solution for this" kind of establishment. Show us what you've tried, we'd be happy to help.

Comment: @AymanSafadi +1 just for the "young chap" `:D`

Comment: How much is up for grab mate! look now we should discuss the money first lol. :)) please read this for quality question: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: ... the DOM already knows what order thing are in, you don't need to hack in refs. Go read the funny manual.

Comment: Make it a gran and you got a deal ;)

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that you should have shared some of your code (what you've tried), and I'm assuming you are familiar with Sortable plugin that you are using. You should run the below code on success event of Sortable so as soon as you sort any LI, the other list will be sorted too. Anyways,

Try this:

```
//This line stored the LIs in a temp variable and remove it
var $cachedList = $('<div />').html($('#second_list').html());
$('#second_list > li').remove();

//This line loads up the first UL's LIs and replaces the content for each LI 
//using $cachedList. 
$('#second_list').html($('#first_list').html()).find('li').each(function () {
    $(this).html($cachedList.find('li[ref="'+$(this).attr('ref')+'"]').html());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AR8px/